# Integers starting at 1 and ending at 5 that are divisible by 9.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find the integers starting at 1 and ending at 5 that are divisible by 9.

An integer is a multiple of 9 if:
$$n = a_k a_{k-1} \cdots a_1 a_0 \Rightarrow a_k+a_{k-1}+\cdots a_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$

**My attempt:**

$1+ a+b+c +5 \equiv 0 \pmod{9} \Rightarrow a+b+c \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$

So $a+b+c = 3 \vee a+b+c = 12 \vee a+b+c = 21$ Because $a,b,c \in [9]$

For $a+b+c = 3$ is obvious that $4! -2!$.
Because the maximum value of a,b,c is 3, that is, 4 digits less when the solution is (1,1,1) which counts by two.

For the other two equations I don't understand how to start because the cases aren't that obvious. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like you want to find the _number_ of _5-digit_ integers starting with $1$ and ending with $5$. In any case, my answer assumes this. But please edit your question to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a+b+c\equiv 3\bmod 9$, so $abc\equiv 3\bmod 9$ (where $abc$ denotes the 3-digit integer equal to $100a+10b+c$). So $abc$ can take every ninth value between $3$ and $993$ inclusive. You can take it from there.

Comment: In fact, shouldn't this work for any number of digits? Any value with digital root $3$ can be the middle set of digits, which should always be anything between $\cdots 003$ and $\cdots 993$.

Comment: @EricSnyder: Yes, of course. But then what is the question?

Comment: I guess we technically don't know which case the OP was asking about, just thought I'd point out that it ought to work for any number of digits.